# Orange: Possible bug in the class_distribution attribute of the rules in Orange.classification.rules.RuleClassifier.rules?

Tags: python, orange

According to the Orange documentation, the class_distribution attribute of a rule is "distribution of class in data instances covered by this rule." However, if I apply a rule to the data instances from the dataset used to derive the rule, the number of instances that fire the rule r sometimes differ from the counts in r.class_distribution.

For example, if I use the adult_sample dataset provided with the Orange package and the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import Orange
data = Orange.data.Table("C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\Orange\datasets/adult_sample")

cn2_learner = Orange.classification.rules.CN2UnorderedLearner()    
#only want to learn rules for class0:
cn2_learner.target_class = 0
cn2_classifier = Orange.classification.rules.RuleLearner.__call__(cn2_learner, data, 0)
RS = cn2_classifier.rules #rule set

rulesFired=[[r(d) for r in RS] for d in data]

#Find what rules fire for each data instance
classV = np.array([d.get_class()==data.domain.class_var.values[1] for d in data]).astype(int)
ind0 = np.where(classV==0)[0]  #indices of data with class 0
ind1 = np.where(classV==1)[0]  #indices of data with class 1
rulesFired0=np.delete(rulesFired, ind1,0) #indicates what rules fired for each class 0 instance
rulesFired1=np.delete(rulesFired, ind0,0) #indicates what rules fired for each class 1 instance
ruleFreq0 = np.sum(rulesFired0,axis=0) #how many class0 instances fired for each rule
ruleFreq1 = np.sum(rulesFired1,axis=0) #how many class1 instances fired for each rule

#Check to see if instances that fired rules match up with r.class_distribution
for ind in range(len(RS)):
    r=RS[ind]
    if r.class_distribution[0] != ruleFreq0[ind] or r.class_distribution[1] != ruleFreq1[ind]:
        print ind  #print indices of rules with mismatches
```

32 out of 82 rules don't have rule.class_distribution match the ruleFreq as defined above.
Let's use RS[5] as an example:

```
#IF education=['Prof-school'] AND age>31.0 THEN y=>50K<3.000, 0.000>
RS[5].class_distribution = <3.000, 0.000> .
```

According to this, 3 instances from class 0 fired the rule, however, ruleFreq0[5] = 7, meaning when I run the rule on all of the data, 7 instances from class 0 fire the rule.
These 7 instances are indexed by ind0[np.where(rulesFired0[:,5])[0]]. Some examples are:

```
#data[220]: [43.000000, 'Private', 350661.000000, 'Prof-school', 15.000000, 'Separated', 'Tech-support', 'Not-in-family', 'White', 'Male', 0.000000, 0.000000, 50.000000, 'Columbia', '>50K']
#data[240]: [43.000000, 'State-gov', 33331.000000, 'Prof-school', 15.000000, 'Married-civ-spouse', 'Prof-specialty', 'Husband', 'White', 'Male', 0.000000, 1977.000000, 70.000000, 'United-States', '>50K']
#data[372]: [41.000000, 'Private', 130126.000000, 'Prof-school', 15.000000, 'Married-civ-spouse', 'Prof-specialty', 'Husband', 'White', 'Male', 0.000000, 0.000000, 80.000000, 'United-States', '>50K']
```

Finally, here are my questions:

1. Is this a bug in the Orange code or does the class_distribution attribute specify something other than the number of instances (from the entire dataset used to learn the rules) from each class that fire the rule?
2. Is this class_distribution used to calculate the quality of the rule? This would mean an error in the class_distribution calculation leads to an error in the rule quality calculation.

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, the `class_distribution` actually holds the class distribution at the time when the rule was induced (i.e the class distribution without all the instances covered by previously induced rules).

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. Perhaps the description in the documentation should reflect that. It seems the rest of the rule attributes also only consider the instances not covered by previously induced rules.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, does Orange have an attibute that is similar to "class_distribution" but covers all instances no matter an instance has been covered or not by previously induced rules? Thanks!